# Visual Studio 2010 Compare Wildcard

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

This is new territory for me, VB and visual studio 2010.. I just need to make one change to a piece of code to improve functionality.

```
If UCase(dvPlaceDisplayList.Item(i)("PlaceName")) >= UCase(ToolStripTxtFind.Text) Then
```

The issue I am having is that several place names are prefixed with 'The' ..

I need to change the code to **Contains** or similar using **wildcards**

As VB is new to me and googling has not provided any answers...here I am

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use:

```
If UCase(dvPlaceDisplayList.Item(i)("PlaceName")) LIKE "*" & UCase(ToolStripTxtFind.Text) & "*" Then
```